# Daniell Integral for Functions that are not $\mathbb R$-valued

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The definition of Daniell's integral is that it it is a non-negative continuous linear operator $I$ from $H\subseteq\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R$, where $H$ satisfies

- if $h\in H$, then $|h|\in H$, and
- $H$ is a linear subspace of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, the set of all bounded real-valued functions.

I wonder whether this definition can readily extended to functions with values in arbitrary (Banach) spaces. For example, consider the set of all continuous functions between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. Then there exists a notition of boundedness, namely all functions $f$ with $\Vert f\Vert_Y \leq C$, i.e. $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ is a well-defined set. So one may chose a suitable subset $H$ of $\mathcal B(X,Y)$ and proceed. It should therefore be possible to define, mutatis mutandis, a Daniell integral for values outside $\mathbb R$ or am I missing a key point here? Because so far I have never seen the Daniell integral defined for functions that are not real-valued.

Comment: I read a paper in undergrad which said that essentially lebesgue integration is equivalent to daniell integration. You can extend lebesgue integration to complex measures, and extended real, so you can probably define a daniell integral in that way too

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the Daniell–Bochner integral $\int$ for Bochner-measurable functions $f: X\to Y$, where $X$ is a Daniell integral space and $Y$ is a Banach space.

Bogdanowicz, Witold M. 1973. “Daniell and Daniell—Bochner type integrals.” In Vector and Operator Valued Measures and Applications, edited by Don H. Tucker and Hugh B. Maynard, 43–50. Academic Press. https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-702450-9.50010-5.